# paging and binding schemes in memory management

Tags: operating-system, paging, memory-address

The concept of paging in memory management can be used with which all schemes of binding?
By binding, I mean "mapping logical addresses to physical addresses". In my knowledge there are three types of binding schemes compile time, load time and execution time binding.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @MartinJames yes I have added a "?" to my question which was seeming to be a statement   LOL

Answer (score 1):

Paging is not involved in compiling, so we can rule that out.

*Load time* can have to meanings - combining the object modules of a program and libraries to produce an executable image (program) with no unresolved symbols (unix definition) *OR* transferring a program into memory so it may execute (non-unix).

What unix calls *loading*, some other systems call *link editting*.

Unix *loading*/link-editting is really part of compiling so doesn't involve paging at all.  This operation does need to know the valid *program addresses* it can assign, which will permit the program to load.  Conventionally these are from 0 to a very large number like 2^31 or 2^47.

Transferring an image to memory and executing can be considered either phases of the same thing, or in *demand loading* environments, exactly the same thing.  Either way, the bit of the system that prepares the program address space has to fill out a set of tables which relate a *program address* to a *physical address*.

The *program address* of main() might be 0x12345; which might be viewed as offset 0x345 from page 0x12.  The operating system might attach that to *physical page* 0x100, meaning that main() might temporarily be at 0x100345.  Temporarily, because the operating system is free to change this relation (conventionally called a *mapping*) at any time.

The dynamic nature of these mappings is a positive attribute of paging, as it permits the system to reformulate its use of physical memory to meet changing demands.